# Sherlock Holmes tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [sherlock-holmes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes) tag is apparently for *Works based on the British Detective created by Arthur Conan Doyle*. While questions on all Sherlock Holmes works are to be tagged with this, questions on *Sherlock Holmes (2009)* appear to be only tagged with this single tag.

I have now created a [sherlock-holmes-2009](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-2009) tag for this film. Is this fine? Should the tag be [sherlock-holmes-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-1) instead in line with [sherlock-holmes-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-2)?

Comment: FYI - I appreciate your enthusiasm for editing - and it is to be encouraged in general.  However its considered kind of bad-form to do so many edits that you blast new questions off the front page with edits of old stuff.  This reduces the visibility of new content where people want an answer.  Again, I really appreciate you doing the work, and don't stop - just spread it out a bit more - Thanks.

Comment: I understand :) (/me points @DForck42 : _He_ started it, Sir! :P)

Comment: lol - no problem.

Comment: Attention @Tom :)

Comment: @coleopterist also want to raise this question. But you done it first. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must admit my first reaction to this was that we shouldn't have a tag for 'generic works about ACD's Sherlock Holmes.  However I thought about an equivalent character, and looked up the [james-bond](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond) tag which is widely used as a generic tag for the character / movie franchise.  So I think you are probably right.

Personally since there is a widely used [sherlock-holmes-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-2) tag, I would suggest using [sherlock-holmes-1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-1) rather than [sherlock-holmes-2009](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sherlock-holmes-2009)